# Checking if an integer is a palindrome using either a string or a dict

Tags: python, performance, comparative-review

I have solved the palindrome question on LeetCode today, but I wasn't happy with the original solution - I used strings, it worked slowly and used a lot of memory.

So I rewrote the answer using a dictionary approach instead knowing that looking up a value in a dictionary has lower time complexity than searching through a list, but the results were strange - my latest answer is much better in terms of memory use (better than 94.65% of other submissions), but it became significantly slower. As you can see in the image below, my last submission is much slower than the first, but memory use has improved a lot:

[image]

My original solution was this:

```py
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:        
        s = str(x)
        
        if len(s) == 1:
            palindrome = True
            
        i = int(len(s)/2)
        
        for p in range(i):
            if s[p] != s[-(p+1)]:
                return False
            else:
                palindrome = True
        
        return palindrome
```

And the updated version is:

```py
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:        
        s = {i:j for i,j in enumerate(str(x))} 
        i = (max(s)+1)//2
    
        if max(s)+1 == 1:
            return True
        
        for p in range(i):
            if s[p] != s[max(s)-p]:
                return False
            else:
                palindrome = True
        
        return palindrome
```

Can anyone explain why the latest version is so much slower? I thought it should be faster...

What should I change to improve the speed?

**EDIT:**
New version based on *@hjpotter* comment. Now I only have 1 call to `max()` in the entire script and yet it's even worse - **168ms and 13.9 Mb**. I don't understand what's happening here:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        s = {i:j for i,j in enumerate(str(x))} 
        m = max(s)
        i = (m+1)//2
    
        if m+1 == 1:
            return True
        
        for p in range(i):
            if s[p] != s[m-p]:
                return False
            else:
                palindrome = True
        
        return palindrome
```

Comment: You have 2 calls to `max`

Comment: Is `max()` that expensive to use? What could I replace it with?

Comment: @hjpotter92, I just added a variable `m = max(s)` so that I call `max()` only once in the entire script, but for some reason results are even worse - now it's **168ms** and **13.9Mb** memory use. My worst solution by far. Makes no sense.

Comment: might just be an issue with executor environment then.

Comment: Try with storing `len(s)` from first solution and check results.

Comment: Timings on LeetCode are absolute garbage. I've had one solution be top 10% and bottom 10% just by running it multiple times. Have you timed this multiple times yourself on a computer with minimal usage? (unlike LeetCode's servers) Are you certain that the timings are accurate and uneffected by external load?

Comment: You aren't searching through a list, you're directly finding the thing you want. Your list code is not slow because of that.

Comment: I don't understand why you need your "else"? You just loop through your number, and if something doesn't match (not a palindrome), you return False. If everything matches, why not just return True at the end? Setting palindrome to True every time might not mean a lot, but why bother?

Comment: @Nyos, true. Also as per Konrad Rudolph's answer below the variable `palindrome` is not necessary at all. I could just have `return True` at the end of the function and if something is not a palindrome it will exit out with `return False` during the `for` loop. Actually, the reason I had the variable originally is because in the early version I declared `palindrome = False` in the beginning of the function and so `else` was there to set it to `True` when conditions are right. When I changed the code I didn't think about removing `else`.

Comment: Okay so for some reason I stumbled on this question on my home page, I just wanted to point out that on my computer: `s = str(x); return s == s[::-1];` is even faster

Comment: Note that this will be faster if you use a different algorithm that doesn’t create another data structure. It’s possible to solve this using `ceil`, `log10`, and some arithmetic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dictionary key access is slower than array index access. Both is in O(1), but the constant time is higher for the dictionary access.

### Is there actually a difference?

I'm not sure how leetcode runs the code, so let's make a proper speed analysis:

[image]

generated by

```py
# Core Library modules
import operator
import random
import timeit

# Third party modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns


def is_palindrome_str(x: int) -> bool:
    s = str(x)

    if len(s) == 1:
        palindrome = True

    i = int(len(s) / 2)

    for p in range(i):
        if s[p] != s[-(p + 1)]:
            return False
        else:
            palindrome = True

    return palindrome


def is_palindrome_dict(x: int) -> bool:
    s = {i: j for i, j in enumerate(str(x))}
    i = (max(s) + 1) // 2

    if max(s) + 1 == 1:
        return True

    for p in range(i):
        if s[p] != s[max(s) - p]:
            return False
        else:
            palindrome = True

    return palindrome


def generate_palindrome(nb_chars):
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    prefix = "".join([random.choice(chars) for _ in range(nb_chars)])
    return prefix + prefix[::-1]


def main():
    text = generate_palindrome(nb_chars=1000)
    functions = [
        (is_palindrome_str, "is_palindrome_str"),
        (is_palindrome_dict, "is_palindrome_dict"),
    ]
    functions = functions[::-1]
    duration_list = {}
    for func, name in functions:
        durations = timeit.repeat(lambda: func(text), repeat=1000, number=3)
        duration_list[name] = durations
        print(
            "{func:<20}: "
            "min: {min:0.3f}s, mean: {mean:0.3f}s, max: {max:0.3f}s".format(
                func=name,
                min=min(durations),
                mean=np.mean(durations),
                max=max(durations),
            )
        )
        create_boxplot(duration_list)


def create_boxplot(duration_list):
    plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 4), dpi=300, facecolor="w", edgecolor="k")
    sns.set(style="whitegrid")
    sorted_keys, sorted_vals = zip(
        *sorted(duration_list.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    )
    flierprops = dict(markerfacecolor="0.75", markersize=1, linestyle="none")
    ax = sns.boxplot(data=sorted_vals, width=0.3, orient="h", flierprops=flierprops,)
    ax.set(xlabel="Time in s", ylabel="")
    plt.yticks(plt.yticks()[0], sorted_keys)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("output.png")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

There clearly is a difference. And that is for a palindrome. My initial thought was that the generation of the dict is overhead. If you have a long string which clearly is no palindrome (e.g. already clear from the first / last char), then the first approach is obviously faster.

Comment: Nice usage of box plot. Consider a violin plot as an alternative :)

Answer (score 18):

Apart from performance, there are several other problems in your implementation which the other answers did not address.

1. [This should not be a class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0). It should be a function, because it being a class offers no advantage whatsoever and it makes its usage more complex.
2. The variable `palindrome` is unnecessary and confuses the reader: this variable is *always* going to be `True`. So remove it.
3. Don’t cast the result of a division to `int`. Use integer division instead.
4. The `if len(s) == 1` check is redundant: its logic is already subsumed in the subsequent code.
5. Use descriptive variable names: `s` for an arbitrary string is fine but `i` to denote the middle index of a sequence is cryptic.

An improved implementation (without changing the algorithm) would look as follows:

```
def is_palindrome(n: int) -> bool:
    s = str(n)
    mid = len(s) // 2
    for i in range(mid):
        if s[i] != s[-i - 1]:
             return False
    return True
```

Or, using a generator expression:

```
def is_palindrome(n: int) -> bool:
    s = str(n)
    mid = len(s) // 2
    return all(s[i] == s[-i - 1] for i in range(mid))
```

… and of course this whole loop could also be replaced with `return s[:mid] == s[: -mid - 1 : -1]` because Python gives us powerful subsetting.

---

I also want to address a misconception in your question:

> looking up a value in a dictionary has lower time complexity than searching through a list,

That’s only true if the dictionary has the same size as the sequence (more or less …), and if looking up the key is *constant*. Neither is true in your case. But what’s more, you still need to *construct* the list/dictionary, and you completely omit the complexity of these operations.

In fact, the first thing your dictionary does is *also* construct the sequence — namely, by invoking `str(x)`. It then goes on to *traverse the whole list!* Because that’s what `i:j for i,j in enumerate(str(x))` does.

So before even starting your algorithm proper, it has already performed *more work* than your other implementation which, after all, only needs to traverse *half* the string. Even if you stopped at this point and returned, the second implementation would already be slower than the first, and you haven’t even finished constructing the dictionary yet (constructing the dictionary from key: value mappings *also* takes time).

As for the actual algorithm, you’re *still* traversing half the string, so once again you are doing the same work as your initial algorithm. This means you have the same asymptotic complexity. But even that part of the second algorithm is slower, because a dictionary is a much more complex data structure than a plain sequence, and each key access of the dictionary (`s[p]`) is substantially slower than the same access on a string or list would be.

Comment: Thanks Konrad! That was very informative! I'd just like to address the first point - this is simply the default way Leetcode structures the answer. The class and function name are given to you even before you start writing any code. Personally, I would never call a Python function `isPalindrome()` like you see in my examples - I'd name it in the same way you did in your answer.

Comment: The reason the dictionary is not faster than the list is primarily because the list code wasn't slow to begin with. *It does not search through the list.*

Comment: "This should not be a class.": This is due to leetcode. They give you a template to fill and it has to be a class. There is no way around it, although I agree with the statement outside of the platform.

Comment: Very nice review!

Answer (score 11):

> So I rewrote the answer using a dictionary approach instead knowing that looking up a value in a dictionary has lower time complexity than searching through a list

In this case a dictionary is slower than a list-like indexing. A string / list provides direct access to its elements based on indices, while a dictionary -- which is normally implemented as a hash table -- needs more computation such as computing the hash values of keys.

> ```
> for p in range(i):
>     if s[p] != s[max(s)-p]:
>         return False
>     else:
>         palindrome = True
> ```

Here, `max` is called repeatedly -- and unnecessarily -- in the loop. There are two problems:

1. The value `max(s)` is unchanged so it should be computed only once outside the loop and the result can be stored and accessed inside the loop.
2. `max(s)` requires comparing all keys of `s`. In this case, using `len(s) - 1` yields the same value and it is faster.

There are some Python-specific improvements that could speed up the program. For example, the following implementations should be faster in most cases because they replace explicit `for` loops in Python with implicit ones, which are implemented in lower-level, interpreter-dependent languages (such as C) and therefore are much faster:

Solution 1:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        s = str(x)
        return s == s[::-1]
```

Solution 2:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        s = str(x)
        mid = len(s) // 2
        return s[:mid] == s[:-mid-1:-1]
```

Comment: +1 for the `return s == s[::-1]`. Admittedly, you have to know that this is an idiom for reversing a string, but it is very sweet and simple once you understand that.

Comment: @MichaelGeary, yeah, I didn't know this idiom. Definitely makes things so much simpler!

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing up *searching* and *accessing*. If you're looking for the value for a index/key, that's accessing. If you're looking for a particular value, without knowing its index/key, that's searching. Accessing is O(1) for both lists and dictionaries[1][2]. While they are the same time complexity, using a dictionary can take longer, due to the overhead of hashing, and the fact that a hash table takes up more space than list. Under the hood, a dictionary is an array with the indices being the hash values of the keys, and the entries being the values for the indices that are the hag value of a key, and null for indices that aren't. When you access a value in a dictionary, it takes the key you give it, hashes it, then looks at the list for the entry there.

[1] Accessing is treated as being constant time, but that is somewhat of a simplification. Larger data sets do have longer access times. For one thing, if the data become large enough, it'll have to be moved out of active memory, so strictly speaking the time complexity is a non-constant function of the size of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Time complexity of Orignal Solution u made : O(i)--only using a for loop.
Time complexity of your new solution Containing enum:  as you are using enum it takes time O(n) and then u are running a for loop O(i),which you can see in your run time.some overhead from enum can be seen.
Note:there comes time with using function (everything is not ultra fast or optimal).

Answer (score 1):

Lol you believe LeetCode's timing is proper?

If you actually want to see speed differences between those solutions, with LeetCode's test cases and on LeetCode, I suggest running the solution 100 times on each input:

```
class Solution:
    
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:        
        for _ in range(100):
            result = self.real_isPalindrome(x)
        return result
    
    def real_isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:        
        # Your real solution here
```

And then you should still submit several times and take the average or so, as times for the exact same code can differ a lot depending on server load.

I did that with your three solutions and the times were about 1200 ms, 4300 ms, and 2600 ms. Since that did 100 times the normal work, the actual times of the solutions were about 12 ms, 43 ms, and 26 ms. The difference between that and the time shown for a regular submission of a solution is the judge overhead, which LeetCode brilliantly includes in the time.

I also submitted your first solution normally a few times, got 60 ms to 72 ms. So if 100 runs of your solution take 1200 ms and one run takes 66 ms, then you have:

```
JudgeOverhead + 100 * Solution = 1200 ms
JudgeOverhead + Solution = 66 ms

Subtract the second equation from the first:
=> 99 * Solution = 1134 ms

Divide by 99:
=> Solution = 11.45 ms

And:
=> JudgeOverhead = 66 ms - 11.45 ms = 54.55 ms
```

Oh and the ordinary

```
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool:
        s = str(x)
        return s == s[::-1]
```

solution got about 420 ms with the 100-times trick. Subtract 55 ms judge overhead and divide by 100 and you're at 3.65 ms for the solution. So in that case, the judge overhead absolutely dwarfs the actual solution time, and together with the time variance, the shown time for a normal single-run submission is absolutely meaningless.